# Regex for twitter data for hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, regex-group

I have the following Twitter data.

The data divide in two part:

```
@Username
```

And tweet or text:

```
RT @username: Stay behind, or take the jump (anything in text or tags and emoji)#@name
```

@name
Jjjjjjjjj
Dhdkeueh
Sjdyeh
@kdudiwi
.....

```
RT @username: thehdydvekdgeke
```

Hshedhdkdjfnfjfkfmfmhdkalshsh+£) #&#(#(£63+kdjdj☺☺
RT @username: this sing kdudhekhh juygg jyttt hyyg

## £jdhdieo+3-) £) 7--uuueoehrmwowyeheldyejelwyej

Djdyegeleisyhekelsudhejwksi

This is the data
I want to divide the data in two part first is username and second is tweet.

The regex I make is:

```
^(RT\s[^ ]*)\s([\W]*[\H]*[\w\s@#;:!?+(+-_#)]*)$
```

The first part is working but second part is not.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
with your_data as (
 select 'RT @username: Stay behind, or take the jump (anything in text or tags and emoji)' as str
 )

 select regexp_extract(str,'^RT\\s(\\S*)\\s(.*)$',1) as username, 
        regexp_extract(str,'^RT\\s(\\S*)\\s(.*)$',2) as tweet
    from your_data;
```

Result:

```
OK
username        tweet
@username:      Stay behind, or take the jump (anything in text or tags and emoji)
Time taken: 1.092 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Use `'^RT\\s(\\S*):\\s(.*)$'` if you do not want ':' in the username.

Or `'^RT\\s(\\S*):?\\s(.*)$'` if `:` is optional:

```
with your_data as (
 select 'RT @username Stay behind, or take the jump (anything in text or tags and emoji)' as str
 )

 select regexp_extract(str,'^RT\\s(\\S*):?\\s(.*)$',1) as username, 
        regexp_extract(str,'^RT\\s(\\S*):?\\s(.*)$',2) as tweet
    from your_data;
```

Result:

```
OK
username        tweet
@username       Stay behind, or take the jump (anything in text or tags and emoji)
Time taken: 28.587 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: I have a data file on this file  have many line I write the pattern how data actually are in tweet part there many lines many spaces in different language also

Comment: @Ajazsheikh It is still not clear what the problem is. Could you please provide clear example and problem statement

Comment: RT @username: hi wassup https//wuusksksihsii #wensdayhajsh                                                                                                                                                         vvvvvv bbhjj                                                                              this pattern data files I have  on this  I have divide in two parts                                                                          [first part username]    [second text]                                     so I need to start regex form RT username end before RT